# What is the best way to profile a Java application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiling

I'm looking for a way to profile a Java application under Eclipse, in order to find the bottlenecks.

As far as I know there are several solutions, but I prefer something that is integrated into Eclipse and easy to use.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I personally liked the JProfiler. I think they are giving 30 days trial version! If you don't want to pay go for jps/jstack tools for analysing stack traces/thread dumps and use Eclipse MAT for analysing memory related issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has a plugin that integrates into eclipse:

[image]
[image]

The [documentation](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.ide) shows how to set up the integration.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.